# Insert data from one sql table row to another where field matches - Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have two tables in an SQL database. They both have five fields: **ID** (PK), **Number**, **InvoiceDate**, **InvoiceNumber**, and **InvoiceAmount**. I am attempting to use Entity Framework to insert the InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, and InvoiceAmount where the field Number matches from one table to the other.

The context for table one is:

```
var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
```

Table two:

```
var pt = new PermanentTestTable();
```

First, I inserted values into table 1 from a CSV, now I am trying to insert into table two where the Number field matches.

```
                var entity = new CsvDbEntities1();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
                tc.Number = item.Number;
                tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
                tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
                tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);

                entity.SaveChanges();
            }
```

I am new to EF and any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: if those are your context just use linq to grab data **var entity = pt.TableName.Where(x => x.ID == 45).Select(x => x);**

Comment: The context is CSVDbEntities1

Comment: Same concept then **var entity = CSVDbEntities1.TableName.Where(x => x.ID == 45).Select(x => x);**

Comment: The only part I dont understand is how to say where x.ID == 'ID on other table', instead of a single number

Comment: Just call the same method for the other table **var entity2 = CSVDbEntities1.TableName2.Where(x => x.ID == 45).Select(x => x);**

Comment: I dont think I am explaining clearly. I would like to select every row where the **Number** field on table one matches the **Number** field on table two and then insert the InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, and InvoiceAmount from the first table in that row to the second table in that row

Comment: Can i see more of your code? Are you trying to pass a number to select, or just select all that have matching numbers?

Comment: So where is your error coming in at?

Comment: I just dont understand how to say: Insert the InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, and InvoiceAmount into table two in the rows where the Number field from table one matches the Number field of table two.

Comment: Both tables have the same five fields, but different data and I only want to insert the last three fields into the second table where the Number field matches

Comment: And to answer your first question, just select all that have matching numbers and insert those last three things

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I dont completely understand but here it goes based of this code :

```
foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
            tc.Number = item.Number;
            tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
            tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
            entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);

            entity.SaveChanges();
        }
```

After you have saved the first table now you query the second for the same record as :

```
var table2entity = entity.PermanentTestTable.Where(x => x.Number == tc.Number).Select(x => x).First();
```

This will query the second table and grab whatever entity is there with the same number

So your end code might look like :

```
var entity = new CsvDbEntities1();

        foreach (var item in model)
        {
            var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload();
            tc.Number = item.Number;
            tc.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            tc.CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate;
            tc.CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber;
            entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);

            entity.SaveChanges();

            var table2entity = entity.PermanentTestTable.ToList();
            table2entity = table2entity.Where(x => x.Number == tc.Number).Select(x => x).First();
            table2entity.CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount;
            //More values inserted here
            entity.SaveChanges()
        }
```

Comment: I think I may have left out a line that is messing it up: `var model = cc.Read<OutstandingCreditCsv>(filePath, inputFileDescription);` Thats what is being enumerated through in the foreach loop when I am reading the values into table 1 from a csv file. When I try to write the `var = table2entity` line, it only gives me `PermanentTestTables` as an option and then won't work because its an Ienumerable. Sorry if Im making this hard to understand. Its all new to me.

Comment: so you dont have the option **where()** after the table2 line?

Comment: If you dont get the where on this line **var table2entity = entity.PermanentTestTable.Where(x => x.Number == tc.Number).Select(x => x).First();**....Try casting it to a list first **var table2entity = entity.PermanentTestTable.ToList();**...then you can **table2entity = table2entity.Where(x => x.Number == tc.Number).Select(x => x).First()**

Comment: Ahhh, yes! Thank you. The `ToList()` fixed the issue

Comment: Almost, the only thing missing is that I don't want it in the foreach loop included above because that was only used to loop the csv data into table 1. So I guess I could put the new code in: `foreach (var number in tc.Number)` to enumerate through all the rows in table 1 with a Number

Comment: Why not in the for loop if you are saving to two tables the same data ?

Comment: but for your way it would be **for each(var number in model)** because tc only has one number right or is it a list of numbers?

Comment: tc is the context of table 1, which is an SQL table. It has 5 columns: ID (PK), Number, InvoiceDate, InvoiceNumber, and InvoiceAmount. It holds hundreds of records. This table holds values that were imported from a csv file in the foreach loop which is shown above. I was just trying to insert all the rows into table two where the **Number** field matches. Does that make sense?

Comment: So I would be trying to do this for a whole set of numbers

Comment: Yea but I think it would be easier if you did it in The for loop and save changes after

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to nest a foreach loop to iterate through every row with a `Number` field. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but I am just happy it's working:

```
var entity = new CsvDbEntities1();

            foreach (var item in model)
            {
                var tc = new TemporaryCsvUpload
                {
                    PoNumber = item.Number,
                    CreditInvoiceAmount = item.CreditInvoiceAmount,
                    CreditInvoiceDate = item.CreditInvoiceDate,
                    CreditInvoiceNumber = item.CreditInvoiceNumber
                };
                entity.TemporaryCsvUploads.Add(tc);

                var ptt = entity.PermanentTestTables.ToList().Where(x => x.Number == tc.Number);

                foreach (var row in ptt)
                {
                    row.CreditInvoiceDate = tc.CreditInvoiceDate;
                    row.CreditInvoiceNumber = tc.CreditInvoiceNumber;
                    row.CreditInvoiceAmount = tc.CreditInvoiceAmount;
                }
                entity.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Comment: Is there multiple Numbers in ptt? Thought there was only one I think the second loop might not be needed

Comment: Plus multiple save changes adds more time to the process you should only call save changes once for this

Comment: There are multiple rows of Numbers. `foreach (var row` may be a better name. Okay, I can delete the other `SaveChanges()`